# Can't see the Site Settings option for SSRS 2012

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I don't seem to have the Site settings option on my SSRS instance.
I have looked at numerous online suggestions including:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/bc47050a-a733-4a27-a55a-64159453d83e

When I try to access the report server url using IE as Run As Administrator, I get a login box everytime.

From reading numerous articles it sounds like I need to the System Administrator in SSRS to view the option but have no idea how to add a user to this system role. I have  so far created New Role using Folder --> Settings for the everyone group and that has at least given me access to the reports and let me publish reports etc.

Other than reinstalling SSRS, any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're folder/object level permission; you need to set the site permissions, too.

To do this you'll need to log in as a server administrator; by default only the **BUILTIN\Administrators** group have the **System Administrator** role in a Report Server.

Once you have logged into **Report Manager** as a server administrator, click on **Site Settings** -> **Security** and add whatever groups/users required:

[image]

See [Granting Permissions on a Report Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156014%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

> At the site level, on the Site Settings page in Report Manager, create
>   a system-level role assignment for each user and group using the
>   predefined roles System User and System Administrator.

If you have UAC enabled you will need to run IE with **Run As Administrator**; if IE is prompting you for credentials you can suppress this by making sure **User Authentication** is set correctly in **Internet Options** -> **Security Settings**; set it to something like `Automatic logon with current user name and password`.

Answer (score 2):

If u don't find site settings option ie home page displays only home,subscription & help,then u run IE as administrator .Go to internet options,tools,security,custom levels,under user authentication

**make automatic login user & password yes** 
- restart the pc 
u'll get the site settings,folder settings tab