# server report URL does'nt work in internet explorer

Tags: deployment, ssrs-2012, reporting-services-2012

i create a report in SSDT, and deploy it, everything was fine.
but i can not open the URL address in internet explorer, and it does'nt show any error.
but i cannot neither open URL address in firefox, but with error of:

User 'DESKTOP-DFI5FUE\aidat' does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed

i did everything, like adding sites from internet option.
could you help me to solve this problem?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryixI.png)

Comment: Can you go to `Site Settings --> Security` of you report server and see how is aidat configured?

Comment: yeah, i go internet explorer -> internet options -> security -> local intranet -> sites -> advanced -> and then i added ''http://desktop-dfi5fue" and " http://desktop-dfi5fue/ReportServer",  you mean this?

Comment: No. In screenshot you have attached there should be a 'Site Setting' option on top right corner. Below link as some information you can try. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107428/cant-see-the-site-settings-option-for-ssrs-2012

Comment: Verify the security settings of the root folder of the report manager. How is it defined?